# How to use substitution args in a yaml file?

Tags: ros, roslaunch, yaml, launch-file, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a yaml file that is used by many launch files. I centralized most of the parameters in the yaml file, but those with substitution arguments do not get properly evaluated. Instead, they get passed in literally (verbatim) to the node. For example:

```
# params.yaml
showRobotModel: true
folderNameForSnapshots: $(find ocu)/snapshots
robot_description: cat $(find ocu)/media/robot_model/NIFTi.urdf
```

How could I avoid copy-pasting the more complex parameters in each launch file? Can they be interpreted somehow in the yaml file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46307/how-to-use-substitution-args-in-a-yaml-file?/) by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 867 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nikola Malešević](https://answers.ros.org/users/24748/nikola-male%C5%A1evi%C4%87/) on 2017-10-24**:
I'm asking the same question 5 years later, but it appears there is no solution.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-10-24**:
YAML is just a markup language and doesn't have a concept of paths or includes. As @dornhenge said, the better way to do this is by creating a launch file which does the substitution and sets the desired parameters.

**Comment by [Nikola Malešević](https://answers.ros.org/users/24748/nikola-male%C5%A1evi%C4%87/) on 2017-10-24**:
I do not agree. My case is that I have other package's large YAML in which I need to change only one parameter depending on the scenario. Having an arg substitution there would be fantastic.
There is an open request here: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1051

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the best way is to set those parameter directly from the launch file instead of loading the yaml. If want to keep it separated make a params.launch from params.yaml and include that.

The way to specific package relative paths would be to use: package://ocu/bla syntax, but afaik the node needs to support that, i.e. call the proper ROS api functions.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-10-21**:
This workaround works in simple cases, but not always. This comes back to another question that I posted, but I need these parameters inside a node with an anonymous name. I am allowed to place  inside my  tag, but not .

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2012-10-21**:
The result is that I must include params.launch outside of the  tag, but then the parameters are not in the anonymous namespace.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Great news for any one still trying to do this. This feature was added recently to Ros Lunar. Check out this [PR](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1354). There is also talk of back porting to kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1